# Events plugin for theater (event = performance of a production)

Tags: plugins

all event plugins I tried had the logic that an event has all information attached to it in a post-type. I have the case where I want to have events which are just performance date/time of a theater production.

So I want one page describing the production and then a list of events / calendar to show the performances. As the performances can occur on different times on different days, the event plugin functionalities for recurring events do not fit (they all only support same time on different days).

What are your suggestions to modeling this case? I guess its actually quite simple, but I can't get it.

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: Be aware that questions asking for plugin recommendations are off topic per the [faq](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @s_ha_dum "What are your suggestions modelling this case" isn't really off topic ... imo.

Comment: @kaiser : Right. I don't think it is necessarily offf-topic. That is why I didn't vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

Two post types.

1. Production - holds absolute range (April 1 - October 30) - also has comma separated field for exception dates (holidays, etc.... black-out dates)
2. Showtimes - holds patterns for repetition. Ex: Every Friday from 7:30 pm to 9:00 pm for one post. Another is Every Saturday from 3:00 pm to 4:00 pm.

Relate them with Posts2posts by scribu, or some other magic. This opens up a world of possibilities, I think.

Can also have master exceptions in an options page or something, to represent times which the whole theater is closed, for example.

During the loop, the Productions whose range intersects with the time period being examined (however you want to set that up), will be loaded, and their related Showtimes as well.

It will be a lot of work, but would be really great exercise!

Answer (score 1):

Note upfront: This is no answer, just a list of things to consider:

1. Lets say you got one event called "Hamlet". Then it gets played every Friday. Times:

   - 16:30-18:30
   - 19:00-21:00
   - 12:00-14:30 (kids performance with a break in between so it's 30min longer)
2. Then there's the other problem is that it could be played for three weeks in December, but not during Christmas days, etc. What then?
3. UI cluttering: Let's say you use custom meta data and have multiple fields - some of them "clonable":

   - Start Date
   - Duration in days/weeks/month/year
   - Repeating Pattern (days/weeks/months/years)
   - Times - clonable so you can adjust it
   - Breaks (days/weeks/months)
   - etc.

It's like a task that can't be solved without writing a *lot* of code. And I can't imagine that there's a solution out there that would already work with that.

The only recommendation that I can give you is a starting point: [Even Organiser](http://wp-event-organiser.com/). I, personally, would take that and try to write child plugins for it.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of [Event Organiser](http://wp-event-organiser.com/).*

Assuming you just want a calendar and/or list of dates - you could use [Event Organiser](http://wp-event-organiser.com/) and create an event for each timeslot and recur that.

- One event is every week on Friday and Saturday at 8pm
- Second event is Every Saturday at 2pm

Unfortunately you then end up with two event pages for the same show, corresponding to the different times. If that's a problem - and since it seems its just one show - you could just suppress all links to the event pages, and point it to a normal page you've created for the performance. (This is possible via editing the templates / shortcode attributes / filters).

This is similar in vein to @GhostToast solution, but does save you bit of time by building on an existing solution as @kaiser suggests.

- Plugin codex: http://codex.wp-event-organiser.com/
- Available filters: http://wp-event-organiser.com/documentation/developers/hooks/ (see event link filter for calendar)
- Shortcode documentation: http://wp-event-organiser.com/documentation/shortcodes/

---

On a side note, architecturally speaking its possible for Event Organiser to handle varying/multiple times. I chose not to simply as its not a much requested feature and is a user interface nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to do this I would ...

1. Save the primary performance information as a [custom post
   type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)-- title, description, etc.
2. And save the performance dates as [custom post meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

As I noted in a comment, questions asking for plugin recommendations are off topic per the faq. Answers recommending a plugin are not off topic but I don't know of a plugin that does that. There may well be one, but I don't know of one.

In the absence of a plugin, you have a fairly significant project. I would suggest that you take a look at the references above, try to get started and edit the question so that it more specifically address a problem in your own attempt to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I have authored just such a plugin for theaters: 
http://wordpress.org/plugins/theatrecms-lite/

There's commercial version too with additional features:
http://www.theatrecms.com

It uses the concept of productions and events, where the former has all the general info and the latter is a specific performance.